# ifstream buffer limit/overflow? C++ (_cnt?)

Tags: c++, file, size, buffer, ifstream

For some odd reason, when my file gets too big in bytes, this error occurs where it stops reading in the correct data. It's as if the buffer stops taking in data at a certain point.

I simplified my code as much as possible to determine the problem, but I've come to realization that it isn't my code, but perhaps a buffer somewhere?

---

If my file is 14,034 bytes and I run this simple code:

```
ifstream inFile("text.txt"); //File is 14,034 bytes
char test;


while(inFile >> test) //This will stop looping at about the 768 - 769 loop
    cout << test;
```

If I force it to go further with a for loop, the results are the same:

```
ifstream inFile("text.txt"); //File is 14,034 bytes
char test;

for(int count = 0; count < 14034; ++count) //The loop will continue until the
    test = inFile.get();                   //end, but for whatever reason, 
    cout << test;                          //inFile stops at 768 - 769 again
```

---

NOW: if I use the same code, but for a smaller file(say 900 bytes), I don't seem to have 
that problem.

*EXACT SAME CODE, JUST DIFFERENT FILE SIZE*

```
ifstream inFile("text.txt"); //File is 900 bytes
char test;

while(inFile >> test) //This loop will continue to the 900th loop without 
    cout << test;     //problems.
```

*EXACT SAME CODE, JUST DIFFERENT FILE SIZE*

```
ifstream inFile("text.txt"); //File is 900 bytes
char test;

for(int count = 0; count < 900; ++count) //The loop will continue until the
    test = inFile.get();                 //end (900) without problems.
    cout << test;
```

---

I've searched for my problem all over Google, and haven't been able to find a solution. The only other thread I found with a similar problem is this one:

[fopen - can't write more than 16K?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714679/fopen-cant-write-more-than-16k)

But even then, no one really understood what they were talking about - so the question was technically unanswered.

Comment: Did you check whether `inFile.is_open()`? Any large file or just that one large file? Filesystem corruption?

Comment: Actually, what are you expecting? That `inFile >> test` reads byte after byte? The `operator>>` reads char after char but skips whitespace.

Comment: Yes, the file is open. Filesystem is not corrupt. And it wasn't any large file, it was just that one. I was attempting to get byte after byte. I tested various methods to see if there was a difference between them and they all returned the same result. I discovered the problem - when reading in character 0x1A for some reason, it interrupts the process. Now I just have to figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to read the file in binary mode, which you can do as follows:

```
std::ifstream file("test.txt", std::ios::binary);
char byte;
while(file.read(&byte, 1)){
    // Do something with byte
}
```

Comment: Correct, this was the solution to the problem. Thank you for your time.